# jquery ajax url not including server path

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm sorry guys but this is making me crazy. This is something I've done before, but for some reason it doesn't work.

I have a html button that fires a js function when clicked and passes a parameter:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="aprobarOperacion(Operacion.value)" data-dismiss="modal">
```

Next, my js function:

```
function aprobarOperacion(numeroOperacion) {

    var serviceUrl = "/Operaciones/AutorizarOperacion";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: (window.BASE_URL == null) ? serviceUrl : window.BASE_URL + serviceUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            operacion: numeroOperacion
        }),
        success: function (data) {
        //some code
        },
        error: function (data) {
        //some code
        },
    });
}
```

The thing is, this ajax function should go to Operaciones controller, and execute an action named AutorizarOperacion which expects a parameter named operacion. The URL should be like http://localhost:port/Operaciones/AutorizarOperacion, but instead the debugger console throws the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED --> http://operaciones/AutorizarOperacion
```

I dont't why but clearly the path is missing the server part. I've tried sereral ways to write the url but they all render like that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `window` has no `BASE_URL` property, so unless you're defining that elsewhere in your code it's not going to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as I understand you need protocol, hostname, and port.

So you should get it like this:

```
var baseUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
```

And then you can use it in your script like:

```
url: baseUrl + serviceUrl,
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. I was used to replicate this function in another app which determines the base URL in the layout, and since I'm building the current app I didn't know about this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.location`

That object has the properties `protocol`, `hostname`, and `port`

```
function aprobarOperacion(numeroOperacion) {
    var baseUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '';
    var serviceUrl = "/Operaciones/AutorizarOperacion";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: (window.BASE_URL == null) ? serviceUrl : window.BASE_URL + serviceUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            operacion: numeroOperacion
        }),
        success: function (data) {
        //some code
        },
        error: function (data) {
        //some code
        },
    });
}
```

BONUS: If you happen to be using babel/es6 you can make things prettier like this, I love using template strings for concatenation.

```
const {protocol, hostname} = document.location;
const port = document.location.port ? `:${document.location.port}` : '';
const serviceUrl = '/Operaciones/AutorizarOperacion';
const url = `${protocol}//${hostname}${port}${serviceUrl}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var serviceUrl = window.location.href + "Operaciones/AutorizarOperacion";  // Raw javascript
var serviceUrl = $(location).attr('href') + "Operaciones/AutorizarOperacion";  // JQuery solution
```